# Wordpress shortcode name as an Attribute

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I was wondering if possible to setup a shortcode and have the name of the shortcode also work as an attribute. How I have mine currently setup is like so

```
add_shortcode('tooltip', 'tooltip');
function tooltip( $atts $content = null) {
array(
    'type'      => '',
);
```

So when someone in wordpress uses the shortcode you type in

`[tooltip type="fruit"]Item Name[/tooltip]`

Although I was wondering is it possible to just use the name of the shortcode as a atts so I can short it a little bit and have it look like this

```
[tooltip="fruit"]Item Name[/tooltip]
```

So pretty much cut out the type attribute and use the name of the shortcode tooltip as an attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, what you're proposing isn't possible. It may be shorter but in my opinion it would be  confusing so I don't see it ever being something that's made possible short of you building the functionality yourself.

Comment: Ok Thanks, that is what I was afraid of, I will have to go with the longer one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use first item in `$atts` array, (`$atts[0]`) when using shortcode tag as attribute.

Working example:

```
<?php

add_shortcode('tooltip', 'tooltip');

function tooltip(Array $atts = array(), $content = null, $tag = null) {

  $args = shortcode_atts(array( 0 => null ), $atts);
  $args['type'] = trim($args[0], '"=');
  unset($args[0]);

  extract($args);

  // Your code starts here ...
  $output = array(
    '$type'    => $type,
    '$content' => $content
  );

  $output = '<pre>' . print_r($output, true) . '</pre>';

  return $output;
}
```

Please replace everything after `// Your code starts here ...`

Executing example:

```
[tooltip="fruit"]Item Name[/tooltip]
```

will return:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [$type] => fruit
    [$content] => Item Name
)
</pre>
```